# Assign Max() MySQL command to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

In my mySQL database, I insert an entry into the db, and then I need to get the number of that last insertion. I have it set to auto-increment. Using the query "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE;" works fine in the database, I just need to capture that number to a variable in PHP.

```
$rowSQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowSQL); 
$largestUID = $row['max']; 
echo $largestUID;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `var_dump($row)` would show you how that max(id) column is showing up in the result array.

Comment: are you looking for the `ID` of the item you just inserted? `$lastInsertID = mysqli_insert_id($con);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AS` modifier in your query. This modifier gives your selected items an alias.

```
$rowSQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxid FROM TABLE"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowSQL); 
$largestUID = $row['maxid']; 
echo $largestUID;
```

Comment: *Ah yes, (aka-my alias)*. - Yet to win the ***"Stickler of the day" award***, if OP  fancy's `max` as in already using in `$row['max']` well.... you know the rest ;) - Yours stands true though. Yet... ah, `max` is an aggregate function and could cause problems if not wrapped in ticks. *"Fred, what were you thinking?"* - As you were :)

Comment: Yep, just wondering if we're all being invited to this year's Boston `?` party ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias name for the calculated column

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as max_id FROM TABLE

$largestUID = $row['max_id'];
```